# how to overwrite a bootstrap class?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to overwrite the following bootstrap class :

```
.table>tbody>tr>td {
    padding: 1px 1px;
}
```

and I am using the following in my HTML but does not works:

```
<style>
    #myID>tbody>tr>td {
      padding: 1px 1px !important;
    }
</style>

<table class="table table-hover" id="myID">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Column 1</th>
        <th class="text-center">Column 2</th>
        <th class="text-center">Column 3</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <!-- Table body -->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center">data 1</td>
        <td style="text-align: center">data 2</td>
        <td style="text-align: center">data 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I do know to much about css, please help me with this.
thanks

Comment: The problem here is what you want is rather vague. You said you want to override (not overwrite) the class. But to what? Just add your own tag on what you want. You don't want the vertical align? You don't want the border color? Then what do you want?

Comment: Hi Kasey, actually the post is very clear what I want "overwrite" not "override", and I've updated the question to adapt for the things that I want

Comment: @shaveax The term is usually "override". You are _overriding_ the existing styles. Show us a [MRE].

Comment: sure, I've updated the post with a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Here is a CodePen using Bootstrap 4.4.1 and your code. Looks to work fine. https://codepen.io/3rror404/pen/VwvJvNP

Answer (score -1):

Try linking your custom CSS stylesheet after the bootstrap and it should work.

Comment: I am putting it inside the style tag on the HTML in the head tag but it does not works